# How do I play music without requiring user action when a notification fires in iOS while the device is locked?

Tags: ios, audio, notifications

How do I play music without requiring user action when a notification fires in iOS while the device is locked? The music needs to be a significantly long audio -- longer than the 30-second limit placed on the notification tone. Other posts on stack**overflow** indicate it can't be done, but I have seen an app that is able to do it. Perhaps it can be done by a roundabout way, though I would like to learn the preferred way.

Here is my code so far:

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "HELLO"
    content.title = "Hello World!"
    content.body = "May the Force be with you."

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.second = 0
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
    // Create the request
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Schedule the request with the system.
    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error=", error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }
    }

// MARK: - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        print("willPresent")

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        print("didReceive")

        print(response.actionIdentifier)

        completionHandler()

    }

}
```

The delegate callback methods don't fire when the device is locked.

Comment: Delegates will be called once user click on the notification. However you can add custom audio files in the settings of the application to change the notification tone.

Comment: @VatsalK I actually need to audio to be a full-blown mp3 file longer than the 30-second limit placed on the notification tone. I will add that detail in my post.